# How can I filter data from dropdown list?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, ggplotly

I would like to filter state on my graph by dropdown list. For instance, I have density graph and dropdown of state list, when I change state graph should be changed as on state. However, with my code when I change the state, it has not something to happen.

My code :

## SERVER

```
  output$overat <- renderPlot({
   filtered <-
   Medi_sum_small %>%
   filter(State == input$e1)
  ggplot(Medi_sum_small, aes(Hospital_Ownership)) +
    geom_density(aes(fill=factor(Hospital_overall_rating)), alpha=0.7) + 
    labs(x="Ownership",
         fill="Overall rating") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x,width=0.3))
  
  })
```

## UI

```
box(
              title = "Select State"
              ,width = 3
              ,solidHeader = TRUE
              ,status = "primary"
              ,selectInput(
                'e1', 'State',
                c("All",unique(Medi_sum_small$State))
              )

Graphs should be changed when I change the stage.
```

Comment: Can you check the `class` of `Medi_sum_small$State` and if it is `factor`, you can do `c("All", as.character(unique(Medi_sum_small$State)))`

Comment: You nee to use your `filtered` variable in `ggplot()`. Correct this - `ggplot(Medi_sum_small,...`

Comment: I try to do it but it's not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment, try this -

```
ggplot(filtered, aes(Hospital_Ownership)) +
    geom_density(aes(fill=factor(Hospital_overall_rating)), alpha=0.7) + 
    labs(x="Ownership",
         fill="Overall rating") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x,width=0.3))
```

Comment: Medi_sum_small is my datasets name. Can I remove it? I see on your code, it doesn't have Medi_sum_small.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can do it, I change my code to :

```
 output$overat <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered <-
             Medi_sum_small %>%
             filter(State == input$e1), 
           aes(Hospital_Ownership)) +
      geom_density(aes(fill=factor(Hospital_overall_rating)), alpha=0.7) + 
      labs(x="Ownership",
           fill="Overall rating") +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x,width=0.3))

  })
```

Thank you so much